# Django default callable referencing to another field of the model

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I have a model that represents pages of a book.

```
class BookPage(models.Model):

def getMaximumPageNumber():
    page_numbers = (i.page_number for i in BookPage.objects.all())
    return max(page_numbers)+1

page_number = models.IntegerField(default=getMaximumPageNumber, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


  //other stuff
```

I want Django to assign a page number automatically upon creation, so I made `getMaximumPageNumber()`. It would work fine if I had only one book. But now I want to reference the `book` from inside this function, so it would be something like `page_numbers = (i.page_number for i in BookPage.objects.filter(book=self.book)`. But the problem is that I can't seem to use `self` in this function, because if I specify it as `def getMaximumPageNumber(self):`, then it would show the  `TypeError: getMaximumPageNumber() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` when I try to access add page screen in admin. Therefore I cannot specify the book I want to find the maximum page of, and this is what I really need to accomplish here.

Is there a way to reference another field of a newly created instance of a model from a default-assigning function? My initial solution was to override the `save()` of this model, but it breaks down some other things I've already written, so using a dynamic "default" would be better, if it is possible in my case.

Comment: No, there isn't. There are several other places where you can solve this problem, such as `save()`, signals, the form or the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier to override the `save_model` in admin model. And it does not cause the damage of overriding model's `save()`

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    max_page = BookPage.objects.filter(book=obj.book).aggregate(Max('page_number'))['page_number__max']
    obj.page_number = max_page + 1
    obj.save()
```

Cheers to Prakhar Trivedi for a [reminder about aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40763036/2052138).

Answer (score 2):

First of all,The max page calculation method should be updated.And your requirement can be achieved like this,by overriding Django model save() method :

```
from django.db.models import Max

class BookPage(models.Model):
    page_number = models.IntegerField(default=getMaximumPageNumber, validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        queryset = BookPage.objects.filter(book=self.book).aggregate(Max('page_number'))
        max_page = queryset['page_number__max']
        self.page_number =  max_page +1
        super(BookPage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```